# Fourier Transform of $sin(5t - \frac{\pi}{4})U(t+8)$

Tags: fourier-analysis, self-learning, fourier-series

I have this function

$$
sin(5t - \frac{\pi}{4})U(t+8)
$$

I know the Fourier Transform of $sin(5t - \frac{\pi}{4})$, which is

$$
\frac{e^{-\frac{\pi^2}{2}fj}}{2j}\left [\delta (f-\frac{5}{2 \pi}) -\delta(f +\frac{5}{2 \pi}) \right ]
$$

So, how would be the Fourier Transform with the shifted unit step?

Comment: What is $U$? Would one not expect the results in terms of the Fourier transform of $U$? If you plug the Euler formula $\sin(a)=\frac1{2i}(e^{ia}-e^{-ia})$ directly into the Fourier transformation, you get a much more elementary derivation of the resulting frequency shift.